# WebView scroll content

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

How can I set page scroll position in WebView?
I get X and Y coord by adding JavaScript on page:

```
window.onscroll = scroll;
function scroll () {"
window.external.notify(window.pageXOffset + \",\" + window.pageYOffset)"
}
```

and save X and y in array :

```
private void WebView_OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] valuePair = e.Value.Split(',');
            XY[0] = int.Parse(valuePair[0]);
            XY[1] = int.Parse(valuePair[1]);
        }
```

But how can I scroll page in WebView when I load page and want to restore scroll position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly there.  You need to save the current position when you leave the page and then navigate back that position when you get back to the page.  Try this:

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    static Point ScrollPosition = new Point();

    private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Coordinates = e.Value.Split(',');
        ScrollPosition.X = double.Parse(Coordinates[0]);
        ScrollPosition.Y = double.Parse(Coordinates[1]);
    }

    private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("SetScrollPosition", new string[] { ScrollPosition.X.ToString(), ScrollPosition.Y.ToString() });
    }
```

In MainPage.xaml:

```
  <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Width="800" Height="500" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html" ScriptNotify="MyWebView_ScriptNotify" NavigationCompleted="MyWebView_NavigationCompleted"/>
```

In HTMLPage1.html:

```
  window.onscroll = GetScrollPosition;

    function GetScrollPosition() {
        window.external.notify(window.pageXOffset + "," + window.pageYOffset);
    }

    function SetScrollPosition(X, Y) {
        window.scrollTo(X, Y);
        window.external.notify(window.pageXOffset + "," + window.pageYOffset);
    }
```